# Is there any way to append a string value to key of a hash in Redis?

Tags: redis, jedis

Redis provided solution to append string value to a key.

> APPEND mykey "Hello"

but not find any solution to append string value to a key of hash.

Comment: there is a pending PR for this feature, can you please add your use case / need?
https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/6006

Comment: I am looking for a solution in existing versions of Redis!

Answer (score 1):

There is [RENAME](https://redis.io/commands/rename) command.

```
RENAME oldkey newkey
```

To clarify, if you want to append `World` to an existing key `Hello`,

```
RENAME Hello HelloWorld
```

Comment: its renaming the key! I want to update value of field in hash. Although RENAME is not for hash

Comment: @veet that was not clear from your question. however, it seems there is no such command